# Synchronizing multiple windows with multiple views in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, synchronization, window

I have an application that shows two windows at the same time. Window A displays a `SurfaceView`, and window B displays a View. Each window (naturally) has its own surface associated with that window. Currently only Window A displays it's `SurfaceView` on Screen, and Window B does not display anything.
I want to switch between the two windows, without the user noticing any flicker, or seeing two windows at the same time. In conclusion, I want to achieve the following effect:

- **Window A** -> Hide SurfaceView A
- **Window B** -> Show View B

Both Happening at exactly the same time.

The problem i'm facing is that no matter how hard i try to synchronize the display, each window displays / hides its view at a slightly different time frame, resulting in a flicker or two views displayed on screen.

I've tried the following method:

- **Thread A** -> Hide view A -> prepare for drawing (`lockCanvas`), and halt (wait) the thread until receiving a signal.
- **Thread B (UI Thread)** -> Show SurfaceView B -> override the view's `draw`, signal thread A to release itself, and then draw.
- **Thread A** -> Receive the the signal and draw on screen (`unlockAndPostCanvas`)

In practice, I got inconsistent results, and the two windows weren't always in sync. Sometimes I can see a frame displaying the two view side by side, and sometimes I can see a frame with no views at all. I even tried using the [Choreographer.postFrameCallback](http://java.labsoft.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/static/docs/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html) to make both windows change their display on the next frame, but again, i wasn't able to achieve full sync.

Anyone have another idea?

Comment: did you ever solve this?